# How to change a column inside a data.frame based on a index in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame with two columns: Name and Index and 2 million rows.

I am sure that all index were written correctly, but I need to verify the 'Name' column.

How do I do to change all Name values based on Index values.

Let me give an example. Suppose we have the following data.frame 'db':

```
db
Index Name
1      Carlos
2      John
3      Bill
4      Mary
1      Cerlas
```

As it is shown, 'Name' should be equal for every Index value, but someone write it incorrectly.

How would I correct it? Is there a solution employing 'dplyr' or 'tidyr'?

I tried the following code, but it has not worked.

```
for (i in unique(db$Index)) {
    db$Nome[db$Index==i] <- db$Nome[db$Index==i][1]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How do we know which is the correct spelling?

Comment: @akrun It doesn't matter, actually

Comment: In that case, posted a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in dplyr. Here we are making the first name given for each Index the name for the entire index:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(Index) %>%
        mutate(Name = Name[1])
```

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If somebody named it correctly for the first element in 'Name' for each 'Index', we can use `data.table` to assign the 'Name' as the first element of 'Name' grouped by 'Index'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(db)[, Name:= Name[1L], by = Index]
```